# To apply search on more than one columns with only one `searchbox` along with pagination

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my try i have done things as following:
1. made one search box and able to apply search on two columns and it is working.
2. applied pagination and it is working too.

problem is, my search has been applied on per page basis but not over whole data at a time.

my code for view(html):

```
<div>
    <input type='text' ng-model='filterValue'  placeholder="Search" />
</div>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="max-width: 1100px;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Mobile number</th>
            <th>Trasanction Id</th>
            <th>Refer Id</th>
            <th>Timestamp</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat="callback in filterUsers()">
            <tr>
                <td>{{callback.mobile_no}}</td>
                <td>{{callback.trans_id}}</td>
                <td>{{callback.refid}}</td>
                <td>{{callback.time_st}}</td>
            </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div>
    <div data-pagination="" data-num-pages="numPages()" data-current-page="currentPage" data-max-size="maxSize" data-boundary-links="true"></div>
</div>
```

js:

```
var callbacks = [
    { mobile_no: '9999988888', trans_id: 'abc123', refid: '676767', time_st: '6:45'},
    { mobile_no: '8888888888', trans_id: 'def123', refid: '787878', time_st: '4:30'},
    { mobile_no: '9999988888', trans_id: 'ghi123', refid: '898989', time_st: '6:45'},
    { mobile_no: '8888888888', trans_id: 'jkl123', refid: '909090', time_st: '4:30'},
    { mobile_no: '9999988888', trans_id: 'mno123', refid: '010101', time_st: '6:45'},
    { mobile_no: '7777777777', trans_id: 'pqr123', refid: '121212', time_st: '4:30'},
    { mobile_no: '4444444444', trans_id: 'stu123', refid: '232323', time_st: '6:45'},
    { mobile_no: '5555555555', trans_id: 'vwx123', refid: '343434', time_st: '4:30'},
    { mobile_no: '1111111111', trans_id: 'abc123', refid: '454545', time_st: '6:45'},
    { mobile_no: '2222222222', trans_id: 'pqr123', refid: '565656', time_st: '4:30'},
    { mobile_no: '3333333333', trans_id: 'abc123', refid: '676767', time_st: '6:45'},
    { mobile_no: '4444444444', trans_id: 'pqr123', refid: '787878', time_st: '4:30'},
    { mobile_no: '5555555555', trans_id: 'abc123', refid: '123456', time_st: '6:45'},
    { mobile_no: '6666666666', trans_id: 'pqr123', refid: '313131', time_st: '4:30'},
    { mobile_no: '9234000000', trans_id: 'abc123', refid: '323232', time_st: '6:45'},
    { mobile_no: '9437000000', trans_id: 'pqr123', refid: '454545', time_st: '4:30'},
    { mobile_no: '7858000000', trans_id: 'abc123', refid: '676767', time_st: '6:45'},
    { mobile_no: '9204000000', trans_id: 'pqr123', refid: '454545', time_st: '4:30'},
    { mobile_no: '7897000000', trans_id: 'abc123', refid: '676767', time_st: '6:45'},
    { mobile_no: '7612000000', trans_id: 'pqr123', refid: '454545', time_st: '4:30'},
    { mobile_no: '9999988888', trans_id: 'abc123', refid: '676767', time_st: '6:45'},
    { mobile_no: '8686000000', trans_id: 'pqr123', refid: '454545', time_st: '4:30'},
    { mobile_no: '8271000000', trans_id: 'abc123', refid: '676767', time_st: '6:45'},
    { mobile_no: '6666666666', trans_id: 'pqr123', refid: '454545', time_st: '4:30'},
    { mobile_no: '9999988888', trans_id: 'abc123', refid: '676767', time_st: '6:45'},
    { mobile_no: '6666666666', trans_id: 'pqr123', refid: '454545', time_st: '4:30'}
];

$scope.filterValue = '';
    $scope.filterUsers = function(){
        return $scope.Callbacks.filter(function(item){ 
           return (item.mobile_no.toString().indexOf($scope.filterValue) > -1 || item.trans_id.toString().indexOf($scope.filterValue) > -1)
        }); 

$scope.currentPage = 1;
    $scope.numPerPage = 10;
    $scope.maxSize = 5;
    $scope.numPages = function () {
        return Math.ceil(callbacks.length / $scope.numPerPage);
    };

$scope.$watch('currentPage + numPerPage', function() {
    var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage);
    var end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;
    $scope.Callbacks = callbacks.slice(begin, end);
});
```

suggest me a way to resolve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to apply search ... then paginate.

What you are doing is to paginate first ... then apply search. Here is how:

Your watch is maintaining the $scope.Callbacks. Then, you are repeating (using ng-repeat) with filterUsers() function.

Change to following:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="callback in Callbacks">
  <tr>
    <td>{{callback.mobile_no}}</td>
    <td>{{callback.trans_id}}</td>
    <td>{{callback.refid}}</td>
    <td>{{callback.time_st}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>

$scope.filterValue = '';

$scope.filterUsers = function(callbacks){
  return callbacks.filter(function(item){ 
    return (item.mobile_no.toString().indexOf($scope.filterValue) > -1 
    || item.trans_id.toString().indexOf($scope.filterValue) > -1)
  });

$scope.selected_users = $scope.filterUsers(callbacks);

$scope.currentPage = 1;
$scope.numPerPage = 10;
$scope.maxSize = 5;
$scope.numPages = function () {
  return Math.ceil(callbacks.length / $scope.numPerPage);
};

$scope.$watch('currentPage + numPerPage', function() {
  var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage);
  var end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;
  $scope.Callbacks = selected_users.slice(begin, end);
});
```

Try it. Tell me if it works or not.